# Dax Condition Calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

PowerBI  conditional calculation is not working.

I have created custom column and I am writing formula where I can get two different calculation for past month and current month

I have tried if else and switch function but it is not giving desired result.

This is Difference I am calculating based on 3 different columns from 3 different data sources.

```
Difference =
    ( SUM ( Opportunity[Revenue] ) + SUM ( 'August 2019'[Revenue] ) )
    - SUM ( '2018 Invoice'[Revenue] )
```

I would like to get result where `(Opportunity[Month]) = 1 ,2,3,4,5,6, 7` then  Difference should be

```
Difference = sum('August 2019' [Revenue]))-sum('2018 Invoice'[Revenue])
```

else

```
Difference =
    ( SUM ( Opportunity[Revenue] ) + SUM ( 'August 2019'[Revenue] ) )
    - SUM ( '2018 Invoice'[Revenue] )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Difference =
IF (
    Opportunity[Month] IN { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
    SUM ( Opportunity[Revenue] )
)
    + SUM ( 'August 2019'[Revenue] )
    - SUM ( '2018 Invoice'[Revenue] )
```

If the `Month > 7`, then the `IF` returns `BLANK()` and you just get the last two terms.